# How to list all targets in make?

Tags: make

Let's say you have a project structure with lots of Makefiles and there is a top level Makefile that includes all the other.

How can you list all the possible targets?

I know writing

```
make
```

and then tabbing to get the suggestions would generally do the trick, but in my case there are 10000 targets. Doing this passes the results through **more** and also for some reason scrolling the list results in a freeze. Is there another way?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is how the bash completion module for `make` gets its list:

```
make -qp |
    awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' |
    sort -u
```

It prints out a newline-delimited list of targets, without paging.

Comment: Maybe add ``| sort -u`` to sort it and remove duplicates

Comment: like the `| sort -u` comment also

Comment: This doesn't work for my Makefile. Another answer did https://stackoverflow.com/a/26339924/482382

Answer (score 6):

FreeBSD and NetBSD make(1) have a built-in variable called `.ALLTARGETS`. You can print out its contents like this

```
make -V .ALLTARGETS
```

That will unfortunately print out a space-delimited list. I find the following more useful

```
make -V .ALLTARGETS | tr ' ' '\n'
```

It prints out each target on its own line.

Comment: If you want to also exclude pseudo targets (`.WAIT`), you can change the command as follows: `make -V '$(.ALLTARGETS:N.WAIT_*:O)'`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simplified version of what the `bash-completion` script does.

```
make -npq : 2> /dev/null | \
    awk -v RS= -F: '$1 ~ /^[^#%.]+$/ { print $1 }'
```

Comment: With this solution private targets such as `.PHONY` or `.ONESHELL` are displayed. Usually, one wants to ignore these.

Comment: @x0s Just add the dot. I've updated it.