# Makefile get list of targets

Tags: linux, shell, regular-expression, make, gnu

I use the following code to get a `makefile targets list` which works OK for most cases, however when you use makefile like this you get only two targets and not all.

The another command doesn't show up

cat `Makefile`

```
command: ## Command description
    @echo "Execution log"

another-command: ## Command description
    @echo "Execution log"

command2: ## Command description
    @echo "Execution log"
```

**The output is:**

```
command
command2
```

I don't understand why I don't getting the command `another-command`,
This is the code

```
`make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\\\/t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}' `;
```

What could be the problem ?

I use this as reference 
[How to list all targets in make?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230047/how-to-list-all-targets-in-make)

[image]

Comment: What are you expecting `[^$#\\\/t=]*` to match? right now, it's excluding no**t**ther I think?

Comment: Please show the actual makefile. The makefile that you show would not produce the output that you show.  Also explain the purpose of your last code fragment.

Comment: @Kusalananda - this is the make file , I will add a picture

Comment: @Kusalananda - I've added the picture to the post, please have a look.

Comment: @NinaS, I can't run your picture through your commands, so it is useless as a test case.

Comment: @vonbrand - but you have the makefile posted and the commands to run, I dont understand what is missing :)

Comment: @NinaS: you don't use the command that was posted in the question you linked to. Use `make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - what is the difference ?

Comment: @NinaS: You have `[^$#\\\/t=]`. It should be `[^$#\/\t=]`.

Comment: @NinaS: does my advice solve your problem?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - When I try it I got error , awk: nonterminated character class ^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#
 source line number 1
 context is
  >>> /^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#/ <<<

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - any idea ?

Comment: Show the exact command you're using.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - Currently I use `make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\\/t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - I tried your option ` make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\/\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'` but I got the error `nonterminated character class ^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#`

Comment: @NinaS: it should work. What version of `awk` are you using? Post output of `awk --version`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - `awk version 20070501`

Comment: @NinaS: are you using BSD? Can you try upgrading `awk` or, as a last resort, installing `GNU awk`? I tried with `awk version 20121220 (FreeBSD)` and it works well.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk - using mac ...

Comment: @NinaS: ok, I see. Try suggestions from my previous comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ make -qp | awk -F':' '/^[a-zA-Z0-9][^$#\\\t=]*:([^=]|$)/ {split($1,A,/ /);for(i in A)print A[i]}'
command
Makefile
command2
another-command
```

In my character set are backslash and tab,
in your set are backslash, slash and "t".

And "another" contains a "t" ;-)

Credits to steeldriver

Comment: Why does this list `Makefile` as a target, though?

Comment: @nsheff "Not a target" built-in, try `make -qp | grep -1 Makefile`